# Loop through objects fields?

Tags: java

I have a class called "Thing" storing the objects of that class in an arraylist, and I am using a for loop to access its' fields.

```
public class Thing {
    String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
```

In the code provided below, the loop is accessing the objects of "Thing" class, one at a time, and hence the count gets incremented always by 1. How would I access the title variable of the object, so that if the title has multiple occurence of the same "word", the count gets incremented accordingly ?

```
public static String wordCounter(List<Thing> list, String word){
    int count = 0;
    for(Thing thing : list){
        if(thing.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase())){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return word + " appears: " + count;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's a thing? Gotta be more specific...

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, a website where you can get help on specific problems with code. Start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and what questions are [suitable for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones are [not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You might also want to check out [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A 'thing' is an object of the class Thing - not great naming i know but just for demonstration purposes

Comment: You need to be a little clearer about what you want to count.  Right now, it appears that you are counting "the number of `Thing`s in the given list whose title contains a given word".  Perhaps you wanted, instead, to count "the total number of occurrences of a given word in the titles of all the `Thing`s in a given list"?

Comment: Yeah essentially I want to count how many times a word appears in the title of that given thing.getTitle(). For example, if the title was "this is an example", if the word passed through the method was "is", then the count would be 1.

Comment: But if the title were "This is what is called the title, and this is very long", the count would be 3?  And the "is" should only be counted if it appears as a whole word on its own, and not just as part of another word?

Comment: Hmmm true, it would seem that I would need to split it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split the "title" into an arraylist.

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(thing.getTitle().toLowerCase().split(" ")));
```

Then you have to check whether this myList contains your "word"

```
for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){
    if(myList.get(i).equals(word.toLowerCasse())){
       count++;
}}
```

Comment: Okay so I currently have:     public static String wordCounter(List<thing> list, String word) {
        int count = 0;
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (thing thing : list) {
            myList = (Arrays.asList(thing.getTitle().toLowerCase().split(" ")));
            if (myList.contains(word.toLowerCase())) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return word + " appears: " + count;
    } ----- But it is still saying there is only one appearance of the word "two" for example, when there is two occurrences of "two"

Comment: Thankyou, is it possible to do this for two fields? So we have done getTitle() but what about if we wanted to do getAuthor() at the same time as getTitle()?

Comment: @JuliaDune You can do it. Just create another list and for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int count(String sentence, String word, int times) {
    if (sentence.contains(word)) {
        times++;
        int i = sentence.indexOf(word);
        String substring = sentence.substring(i + word.length());
        times = count(substring, word, times);
    }
    return times;
}

public static String wordCounter(List<Thing> list, String word){
    int count = 0;
    for(Thing thing : list){
        count = count(thing.getTitle().toLowerCase(), word.toLowerCase, count);
    }
    return word + " appears: " + count;
}
```